# SQLite conditional where clause

Tags: sqlite

I have three tables

```
ZoneTable
ID, Name

UserTable
ID, Name

UserZone
ZoneTableID, UserTableID
```

Now.

```
SELECT ID, Name from ZoneTable
```

gives me the full list of zones.

If i do the following

```
SELECT ZoneTable.ID, ZoneTable.Name from ZoneTable LEFT JOIN UserZone on UserZone.ZoneTableID = ZoneTable.ID WHERE UserTableID = :ID GROUP BY ZoneTable.ID
```

gives me the list of zones the user is allowed in.

Now to make things annoying if a user is allowed in all zones then they don't appear in the UserZone at all.

So is there anyway i can get the list of ZoneTableID's per specific user user, if the count is 0 then don't apply the where clause, if count > 0 then only show the specific zone names, all in one query.

If that makes sense

Thanks

Comment: If I understood, you want to get all ZoneIDs to the user and if the user doesn't have any Zones, you want to get all ZoneNames. Right? Are you sure you want to return different fields? I think these are two complete different tasks/functions. I would recommendate you to split these into two statements.

Answer (score 1):

Note: you don't need to use an outer join, and the query could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM ZoneTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ZoneTableID
             FROM UserZone
             WHERE UserTableID = :ID);
```

---

Anyway, you can add the condition to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM ZoneTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ZoneTableID
             FROM UserZone
             WHERE UserTableID = :ID)
   OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT ZoneTableID
                  FROM UserZone
                  WHERE UserTableID = :ID);
```

or add a second query for the second case:

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM ZoneTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ZoneTableID
             FROM UserZone
             WHERE UserTableID = :ID)
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name
FROM ZoneTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ZoneTableID
                  FROM UserZone
                  WHERE UserTableID = :ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider a NOT IN subquery? As in: where ... OR :ID NOT IN (select usertableid from userzone where usertableid = :ID)